# Why are some angular2 (component) folders prefixed with '+'

Tags: angular

In some angular2 projects the folder structure of ng2 source looks similar to this:

```
app/
  +auth/
    ...
  +home/
    ...
  shared/
    ...
  app.component.ts
  main.ts
```

What does the '+' prefix of auth and home folder indicate?

Comment: It was a practice to indicate folders that contain separate modules that should be lazy-loaded into the application at some stage.

Comment: @HarryNinh Is it still considered best practice?